# Tengo un archivo PHP al cual necesito agregarle validaciones pero cada vez que le agrego las validaciones no se ejecuta o no con los parametros

Tags: php, condiciones

**accion1.php:**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['numero']=$_POST['numero'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simulacion de compras: Aplicacion 1</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Ingrese los datos del/los cliente/s: </h1>
    <form action="accion2.php" method="POST" name="action1">
    <?php
        if ($_POST['numero']=='' && $_POST['numero']==0) 
        {
            echo "<h2>Disculpe, no puede dejar el campo vacio. Por favor intente de nuevo.</h2>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            if (!is_numeric($_POST['numero'])) 
            {
                echo "<h2>Disculpe,el valor del campo debe ser numerico. Por favor intente de nuevo.</h2>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<br>";
            }
            else
            {
                if(isset($_POST['numero']))
                {
                    for($i=0;$i<$_POST['numero'];$i++)
                    {
                        echo "<h3>Datos del cliente Nro.$i: </h3>";
                        echo "<label>Cedula: </label>";
                        echo "<input type='text' name='cedula[]' placeholder='Cedula de Identidad' MAXLENGTH='8'>";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "<label>Nombre: </label>";
                        echo "<input type='text' name='nombre[]' placeholder='Ingrese el nombre'>";
                    }
                }   
                if(isset($_POST['numero']))
                {
                    for($i=0;$i<$_POST['numero'];$i++)
                    {
                        echo "<h3>Compra del cliente Nro.$i: </h3>";
                        echo "<label>Articulo 1:  BsF. 3500 </label>";
                        echo "<input type='text' name='CantArtA[]' placeholder='Cantidad Art.1' MAXLENGTH='5'>";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "<label>Articulo 2:  BsF. 5500 </label>";
                        echo "<input type='text' name='CantArtB[]' placeholder='Cantidad Art.2' MAXLENGTH='5'>";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "<label>Articulo 3:  BsF. 4000 </label>";
                        echo "<input type='text' name='CantArtC[]' placeholder='Cantidad Art.3' MAXLENGTH='5'>";
                        echo "<br>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar datos">
    <input type="reset" value="Borrar datos">
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="inicio.html">Reingresar la cantidad de clientes.</a>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**accion2.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simulacion de compras: Aplicacion 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['cedula']) && isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['CantArtA']) && isset($_POST['CantArtB']) && isset($_POST['CantArtC'])) 
    {
        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
        $cedula=$_POST['cedula'];
        $prod1=$_POST['CantArtA'];
        $prod2=$_POST['CantArtB'];
        $prod3=$_POST['CantArtC'];
        $n=count($nombre);
/*nombre y cedula no pueden estar vacios*/
/*cedula no se puede repetir ni ser menor a 6 digitos*/
/*prod1, 2 y 3 deben ser enteros*/
                for ($i=0; $i <$n ; $i++) 
                { 
                    echo "<h2>------ Datos del Cliente ------</h2>";
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "Nombre: ".$nombre[$i];
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "Cedula: ".$cedula[$i];    
                    if ($prod1[$i]>10) 
                    {
                        $sbt1=($prod1[$i] * 3500);
                        $dsc1=($sbt1 * 0.10);
                        $tot1=$sbt1 - $dsc1;
                        echo "<h4>Articulo N1:</h4>"; 
                        echo" Cantidad $prod1[$i] &nbsp;";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "Precio unitario: BsF. 3500 c/u";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "El articulo 1 obtiene un descuento de 10 &#37, el Subtotal es de: $tot1";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "Descuento: BsF. $dsc1";
                        echo "<br>";
                    }
                    elseif($_POST['CantArtA'] == '') 
                    {
                        echo "------- No se compro este producto -------";
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        $tot1=($prod1[$i] * 3500);
                        echo "<h4>Articulo N1:</h4>"; 
                        echo" Cantidad $prod1[$i] &nbsp;";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "Precio unitario: BsF. 3500 c/u";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "Subtotal: $tot1";
                        echo "<br>";
                    }

                    if ($prod2[$i] > $prod1[$i] && $prod2[$i] < 21) 
                    {
                        $sbt2=($prod2[$i] * 5500);
                        $dsc2=($sbt2 * 0.20);
                        $tot2=$sbt2 - $dsc2;
                        echo "<h4>Articulo N2:</h4>"; 
                        echo" Cantidad $prod2[$i] &nbsp;";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "Precio unitario: BsF. 5500 c/u";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "La compra de este articulo tiene un descuento de 20 &#37, el Subtotal es de: $tot2";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "Descuento: BsF. $dsc2";
                        echo "<br>";
                    }
                    elseif($_POST['CantArtB'] == '') 
                    {
                        echo "------- No se compro este producto -------";
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        $tot2=($prod2[$i] * 5500);
                        echo "<h4>Articulo N2:</h4>"; 
                        echo" Cantidad $prod2[$i] &nbsp;";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "Precio unitario: BsF. 5500 c/u";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "Subtotal: $tot2";
                        echo "<br>";
                    }   

                    if ($prod3[$i] <> $prod1[$i] && $prod3[$i] <> $prod2[$i] && $prod3[$i] >20) 
                    {
                        $sbt3=($prod3[$i] * 4000);
                        $dsc3=($sbt3 * 0.30);
                        $tot3=$sbt3 - $dsc3;
                        echo "<h4>Articulo N3:</h4>"; 
                        echo" Cantidad $prod3[$i] &nbsp;";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "Precio unitario: BsF. 4000 c/u";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "La compra de este articulo tiene un descuento de 30 &#37, el Subtotal es de: $tot3";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "Descuento: BsF. $dsc3";
                        echo "<br>";
                    }
                    elseif($_POST['CantArtC'] == '') 
                    {
                        echo "------- No se compro este producto -------";
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        $tot3=($prod3[$i] * 4000);
                        echo "<h4>Articulo N3:</h4>"; 
                        echo" Cantidad $prod3[$i] &nbsp;";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "Precio unitario: BsF. 4000 c/u";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "Subtotal: $tot3";
                        echo "<br>";
                    }   
                    $stnoiva=($tot1)+($tot2)+($tot3);
                    $stsiva=$stnoiva * 0.12;
                    $total=$stnoiva+$stsiva;
                    $proprod= ($prod1[$i]+$prod2[$i]+$prod3[$i])/3;
                    $provts= ($tot1+$tot2+$tot3)/3 ;
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "El valor de su compra +IVA es de: $total BsF.";
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "El promedio de los articulos vendidos es: $proprod Arts.";
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "El promedio de ingreso de la venta es: $provts BsF.";
                }   
            }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Tengo estas ideas pero no se donde colocarlas para que se ejecute:

```
                if(($cedula=='') || ($nombre==''))
                {
                    echo "No pueden existir campos vacios, por favor revise.";
                    echo "<br><a href='accion1.php'>Volver al formulario.</a>";
                }
                else
                {
                    if ($cedula==$cedula[] )
                    {
                        echo "ERROR: No puede ingresar la misma cedula. <br>";
                        echo"<a href='accion1.php>Volver al formulario</a>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if((!is_numeric($cedula)))
                        {
                            echo "Se deben ingresar unicamente datos numericos, intente de nuevo.";
                            echo "<br><a href='ej2.html'>Volver al formulario.</a>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (strlen($cedula[])<7) 
                            {
                                echo "La cedula no puede ser inferior a 7 digitos, intente de nuevo.";
                                echo "<br><a href='accion1.php'>Volver al formulario.</a>";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if ($CantArtA<0 || $CantArtB<0 || $CantArtC<0 ) 
                                {
                                    echo "Se deben ingresar solo numeros positivos, intente de nuevo.";
                                    echo "<br><a href='accion1.php'>Volver al formulario.</a>";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (!preg_match($patron_texto, $_POST['nombre[]']))
                                    {
                                        echo "Se deben ingresar unicamente caracateres, intente de nuevo."; 
                                        echo "<br><a href='accion1.php'>Volver al formulario.</a>";
```

Comment: tus ideas que tienes serian por javascript  y las de php se validan en el modelo

Answer (score 0):

Amigo en vez de colocar es igual a 0. puedes colocar la funcion isset para validar que los campos efectivamente contengan algo por ejemplo.

```
if (isset($_POST['numero'])){

  echo "<h2>Disculpe, no puede dejar el campo vacio. Por favor intente de nuevo.</h2>";


}

if(isset($cedula),isset($nombre))
            {
                echo "No pueden existir campos vacios, por favor revise.";
                echo "<br><a href='accion1.php'>Volver al formulario.</a>";
            }
```